# navigator backhistory with phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, history

I have two page, page 1 and page 2. page 1 contains fields will contain values ​​and a Next button to go to page 2. Page 2 contains a button before allowing back to page 1. how to display the page 1 when return from page 2 with the same data input before.

i use this code:

```
navigator.app.backHistory();
return false;
```

and I have already used this code

```
if (typeof(navigator) != 'undefined' && typeof(navigator.app) != 'undefined' && typeof(navigator.app.backHistory) == 'function')
    {
        navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
    // standard
    else
    {
        history.go(-1);
    }
```

the problem that there are fields dynamically populate combobox and dynamically  added, if I use this code above   it contained the charge again of these fields are dynamic, and I lost what I selected before.

how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: alooooooooooooo. I need a Help

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the data of all fields and options of page 1 before moving to page 2. on load event of page 1, check for existing data in session and if exist, populate it on page. it may sound difficult and long but it is not. you can create json object of all data and save it like this

```
this.setPageData = function(data) {
    if(data == null || data == '')
        store.setStorageItem('PageData', null);
    store.setStorageItem('PageData', JSON.stringify(data));
}
this.getPageData= function() {
    var data = store.getStorageItem('PagetData');
    if(data == null || data == '')
        return data;
    return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

storing function will go like this

```
this.Store = function() {
this.setStorageItem = function(name, val) {
    localStorage.setItem(name, val);
}
this.getStorageItem = function(name) {
    return localStorage.getItem(name);
}
this.clearStorage = function() {
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

}